# Calculate average degree distribution

Tags: python, igraph

Does anyone know how we can calculate average degree distribution using python-igraph ? I thought it might have a function to so but all I could find was degree_distribution which only returns nodes degree not the average.

Thanks

Comment: `mean(degree(g))` ? This is the average degree. I am not sure what the average degree distribution is. Oh, sorry, this is R, actually, not Python. But probably you can just sum up the degree and divide by the number of nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need to have a separate function to calculate all sorts of summary statistics about the degree distribution; igraph provides a function to calculate the mean of any list of numbers (see `igraph.mean`) and also another function to calculate the degree list so you only need to combine the two:

```
>>> from igraph import Graph, mean
>>> g = Graph.GRG(100, 0.2)
>>> mean(g.degree())
10.8
```

Comment: I was using this: sum(GraphBase.degree(g))/GraphBase.vcount(g). But yours seems simpler. Thanks :)